# What regex can I use to match any valid IP-address represented in dot-decimal notation?

Tags: regex, perl, ip-address

What regex can I use to match any valid IP-address represented in dot-decimal notation?

Comment: Search CPAN. you can find modules such as [Data::Validate::IP](http://search.cpan.org/~neely/Data-Validate-IP-0.10/lib/Data/Validate/IP.pm) for your use

Comment: +1 its a simple and valid question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CPAN is your friend: [Regex::Common](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common) or [Net::IP::Match::Regexp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IP-Match-Regexp).

Answer (score 15):

```
if($ip=~/^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/ &&(($1<=255  && $2<=255 && $3<=255  &&$4<=255 )))
     {
         print "valid\n";
     }
     else
     {
         print "Invalid\n";
     }
```

Comment: dear friend, please recommend  Data::Validate::IP  from now on.
your dear friend.

Comment: @xxxxxxx Why? Tho code is simple enough to be checked. IPv4 will most likely not change and on some environments adding a module dependency is not so trivial.

Answer (score 5):

I like this one ... pretty much as Steve Hajducko's but using quoted reg ex which rooooock!

```
my $ip = '120.140.255.254'; # for example

my $ipno = qr/
    2(?:5[0-5] | [0-4]\d)
    |
    1\d\d
    |
    [1-9]?\d
/x;

if ( $ip =~ /^($ipno\.){3}$ipno$/ ){
    print "IP OK\n";
};
```

I went for an interview at Arm in Cambridge, UK. They asked me to write one on the board and I wrote some lame one .. and later ... brooding on my poor attempt set out to make a better one. Driven by failure? Or maybe just really irritated by it. I still got the job :)

Comment: Nice one. :) do you mind adding a comment to the various parts for people to understand better?

Answer (score 2):

[How do I write a regular expression that matches an IPv4 dotted address?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/22/603788.aspx)

Long story short: Don't do it ^^.

Answer (score 2):

If you can leave a perl module behind - then do it.

what about:

```
if( $ip=~ m/^(\d\d?\d?)\.(\d\d?\d?)\.(\d\d?\d?)\.(\d\d?\d?)/ && 
          ( $1 <= 255 && $2 <= 255 && $3 <= 255 && $4 <= 255 )
) {    
    print "valid IP.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For IPv4 in an A.B.C.D (decimal) format, as a one-liner:

`(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])`

If nothing follows the address on the line, it can be contracted to:

`(?:(?:[01]?\d?\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.|$)){4}`

Have fun.

Comment: inet_aton typically handles a lot more formats than just "A.B.C.D", try "ping 10.4" or "ping 0x0a.077.0.4" and see what happens.

Comment: ...which is why the limitation "IPv4 in an A.B.C.D (decimal) format" is *clearly stated* for those who actually bother to read. :)

Comment: Users inputting data don't care about your limitations though. :)

Comment: Absolutely, one may either have a specific need to support e.g. IPV6 addresses, or run into those users who **absolutely positively want** to be able to enter non-IPV4 A.B.C.D format IP addresses and still have them pass off as valid, if valid -- but assume for a moment that the highly implicitly stated (via the question tag) "I"m in Perl" assumption was not actually stated.  Assume you're validating a form field in Javascript -- you have neither `inet_aton` nor CPAN to run to the rescue, and maybe you don't want to write a kilometer-long regexp either. :)

Comment: And, for the record, **you** are not qualified to state what planetp's users care or don't care about since you are neither such a user nor are you planetp. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])
```

Actually matches some invalid IP addresses, such as:

192.168.00.001

A slightly more refined solution would be:

```
(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)$
```

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 ip validation with port number

```
if ( $ip =~ /(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})(:(\d{1,5}))?/ )
{
    if( $1 > 255 || $2 > 255 || $3 > 255 || $4 > 255)
    {
        print "invalid ip\n";
        return ;
    }
    if( ( defined $6) && ( $6 > 65536 ))
    {
        print "invalid port\n";
        return ;
    }
    print "valid ip \n";
}
else
{
    print "invalid ip\n";
    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip='123.0.0.1';
if($ip=~/^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/ &&((($1<=255 && $1 > 0) && $2<=255 && $3<=255  &&$4<=255 )))
 {
     print "valid\n";
 }
 else
 {
     print "Invalid\n";
 }
```

Here in this case we are validating 0.0.0.0 will not be consider the valid IP. and supporting all remaining IPs upto 1.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why I don't see this one around anywhere, it's short, concise, and awesome.

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

Comment: It's mainly because perl has features for this sort of thing.

Comment: That'll match 562.93.612.3, which is not an IP.

Comment: What is so awesome about it? The fact that it allows invalid IP addresses too? It would allow `999.999.999.999`.