# Looking for shortest ipv4 matching regexp in Perl TCL

Tags: regex, perl

I was trying to get the shortest regexp for IPV4 in perl

Suppose we have the following

```
my $ip = "192.168.1.23";
$ip =~ /(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/;
$ip =~ /(\d{1,3})(\.\d{1,3}){3}/;
```

Or we can split with dot

Is there any way we can use `\d{1,3}` only once in the expression? Like in our first ip matching expression I am using `\d{1,3}` four times and second expression is using it two times.

Comment: In Perl, yes, you can. Use a subroutine call.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : How we can do that. Can you give me brief

Comment: This will just capture a dotted quartet of 3 digits each. For example, it would match 456.678.910.299, which is not a valid IPv4 address. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221754/how-to-extract-ip-addresses-from-a-text-file-using-perl or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346869/what-regex-can-i-use-to-match-any-valid-ip-address-represented-in-dot-decimal-no

Comment: Why do you tag your perl questions as tcl?

Comment: @melpomene: Reason I tagged as TCL is only syntax is different. Same regexp will work in TCL also just write regexp. I am looking for solution not syntax

Comment: @Nitesh No, TCL uses a different (and incompatible) regex engine. Many Perl features aren't supported (or work differently).

Comment: @melpomene: Agreed. Do you know shorter regexp in Tcl which use \d{1,3} only once

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Can you please tell me regexp for that using subroutine

Comment: @Nitesh I already told you, `.*` is shorter.

Comment: @melpomene : But .* will match everything. It will include words, characters, spaces everything.

Comment: @Nitesh: Why do you want to make it shorter?

Comment: @Borodin: Somebody asked me the same. I was not aware of it. It searched google and then came to this forum again. Just out of curiosity I am asking

Comment: See https://ideone.com/vSuBXi

Comment: @Nitesh `\d{1,3}` will also match lots of things that aren't IP addresses, such as `۶Ⅺ⅗`.

Answer (score 2):

Your current pattern matches many strings that aren't IPV4 addresses, so I can't tell what your criteria are. You may as well have `.*` [as melpomene says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527289/looking-for-shortest-ipv4-matching-regexp-in-perl-tcl#comment64448814_38527289)

Slightly better would be `/[\d.]{7,15}/` or `/(?:\d{1,3}:){3}\d{1,3}/`, but the best way is to `use Regexp::Common` when `$RE{net}{IPv4}` will give you the proper pattern

```
(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))
```

Comment: what is ?: in regular expression